# AWS Maintenance page on S3 FE

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend, load-balancing

i'm looking for to set maintenance page before S3 on our AWS stack.
My situation is the following:

- Frontend: static frontend hosted on S3, React app. To deploy FE we're using our pipeline on Github
- BackEnd: Our backend is on EC2 Instance

For CD/CI we using gitlab, each environment (S3, EC2..) has its dedicated pipeline with artifact management.
How can i deploy easy from aws a maintenance page and have access to prod S3 for test the new environment?
What could be a valid solution while always remaining on the aws cloud?

I'm attach a screenshot of our infrastructure.
Thanks in advance,
BR
J

[infrastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I14aI.png)

I've tried with amplify and beanstalk but it's not working properly.